# Download Outlook attachment that is an Outlook item

Tags: vba, outlook

How to automatically download attachment that is an outlook item?

[image: imag here]

I tried downloading using this vba script but it does not work for outlook item. It works for .txt or any other type of attachment.

```
Public Sub Savisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "D:\userdata\sanakkay\Desktop\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That does not look like `vb.net`... well some of it is mixed with `vb6`. Can you describe what `it doesn't work for outlook item`?

Comment: sry.......... its not vb.net its vba code. this code works for attachments which are in .txt or .excel or other formats but doesnt work for file type outlook . view image for how  outlook format looks like

Answer (score 2):

Outlook items may be named / have subjects with characters that are illegal in file names.

For example the colon character in

> Task Name:KM_CEM_GY

There are at least two standard methods to address this.

[Outlook 2010 VBA How to save message including attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746506/outlook-2010-vba-how-to-save-message-including-attachment)

```
Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, sChr As String)
    sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

[VBA dialog boxes automatically answer solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509399/vba-dialog-boxes-automatically-answer-solution)

```
Function StripIllegalChar(StrInput)
    Dim RegX            As Object

    Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RegX.Pattern = "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
    RegX.IgnoreCase = True
    RegX.Global = True

    StripIllegalChar = RegX.Replace(StrInput, "")

ExitFunction:
    Set RegX = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to download attachment from Outlook, try this.
Private Sub GetAttachments()

```
Dim ns As Namespace
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim FileName As String

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.Folders("MailboxName").Folders("Inbox")

If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
            "Nothing Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each Item In Inbox.Items
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        If Atmt.Type = 1 And InStr(Atmt, "xlsx") > 0 Then
            FileName = "C:\attachments\" & Atmt.FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
        End If
    Next Atmt
Next Item
```

End Sub
Set a reference to MS Outlook and remember, the "MailboxName" is your email address.